# Inner area color for pie-donut highchart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

How to add color in inner area of pie-donut highchart. is it possible with  chart custom code

```
plotOptions: {
          pie: {
                borderColor: '#fff',
                innerSize: '60%',

            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: '#000000',
              connectorColor: '#000',

            }
          }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/3shr7742/. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.circle) to add custom shape like circle.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sebastian says, draw a custom shape:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle

Example:

```
var sgDims = chart.seriesGroup.element.getBBox();    
chart.renderer
.circle(sgDims.width / 2, sgDims.height / 2 + sgDims.y, sgDims.width / 2 - 10)
.attr('fill','#F0F')
.add()
;
```